# Animated sticky header using translate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built the prototype that I'll use for my site header, it is basically a simple navigation that on scroll re-appears on screen in a fixed position (sticky nav). I firstly acheived this by having two  tags in the markup but ideally I'd liek to acheive this using only one.

Here's my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CLJKj)

If you slowly scroll down you should see what I'm trying to achieve here. Heres my javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 60){  
        $('.main-header').addClass("sticky-header");
    }
    else{
        $('.main-header').removeClass("sticky-header");
    }

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 160){  
        $('.main-header').addClass("sticky");
    }
    else{
        $('.main-header').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

There is probably a better way of achieving this using a slightly different approach? I don't like the fact I'm testing for two instances of scroll top, only did this because firstly I need a way to apply the positioning of the header, apply the margin value which does the snazzy transition as if it's moving downwards from the top of the page.

Comment: You can use CSS for this no?

Comment: Nope, I think you've got a pretty good solution there. You could use jQuery CSS (`.css`) but it would do the same thing

Comment: I recommend to read this article http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/ for debouncing scroll. Here a simple fiddle of your solution http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/uB4PL/23/ works fine, just with debouncingg you can get better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace Your javascript with the below one: you will get nice scroll

$(window).scroll(function() {

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0){  
    $('.main-header').addClass("sticky-header");
}
else{
    $('.main-header').removeClass("sticky-header");
}

if ($(this).scrollTop() > 160){  
    $('.main-header').addClass("sticky");
}
else{
    $('.main-header').removeClass("sticky");
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for that. Another question if you don't mind, I came across this nice sticky nav today https://medium.com/@snookca/component-independence-1da9d5c9fc14 Any idea on what the javascript is doing here? All I know is it's adding classes based on a scroll function back to top only...